# RecyclerView does not display any data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've been struggling with this issue for a while. I have an activity (`SerieActivity`) where I allow the user to select various items and give them values. The items are stored in an `ArrayList<Variable>`, where `Variable` is a class that I've defined. The items are displayed in a `RecyclerView`. This works just fine. Upon clicking a button in that activity, the user is sent to another activity (`Result`) that displays the exact same items from the `ArrayList` in `SerieActivity`, with the respective values that the user has input.

In my `Result` activity I have created an instance of the `SerieActivity` class and then made an `ArrayList` to store the values of the original `ArrayList` from `SerieActivity`. However it seems like the RecyclerView from my `Result` class doesn't get populated with data. What could be going wrong?

Here's my code:

**`Variable` class**

```
public class Variable {

    boolean known;
    String unit, name;
    double value;
}
```

**`RVAdapterSerie` - the adapter for the RecyclerView used in the `SerieActivity` class**

```
public class RVAdapterSerie extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapterSerie.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Variable> variableList;

    public RVAdapterSerie(Context context, ArrayList<Variable> variableList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.variableList = variableList;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RVAdapterSerie.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Variable v = variableList.get(position);
        holder.setItems(v);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return variableList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private CheckBox checkBox;
        private EditText editText;
        private TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.value_cb);
            editText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.value_et);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.value_tv);
        }

        public void setItems (Variable variable) {
            checkBox.setText(variable.getName());
            editText.setText(String.format("%.3f", variable.getValue()));
            textView.setText(variable.getUnit());
        }
    }
}
```

**`SerieActivity` class**

```
public class SerieActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ArrayList<Variable> mList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_serie);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.serie_rv);
        RVAdapterSerie rvAdapterSerie = new RVAdapterSerie(this, mList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(rvAdapterSerie);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        populateList();
        rvAdapterSerie.notifyDataSetChanged();

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.serie_fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SerieActivity.this, Result.class);
                intent.putExtra("tag", "serie");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void populateList() {
        mList.add(new Variable(false, "dummyunit", "dummyname", 0));
        mList.add(new Variable(false, "diofishafuio", "ghfuef", 0));
        mList.add(new Variable(false, "diofishdfesffafuio", "ghfuef", 0));
        //add dummy items
    }
}
```

---

**`RVResultAdapter` - adapter for the RecyclerView in `Result` class**

```
public class RVResultAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVResultAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Variable> variableList;

    public RVResultAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Variable> variableList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.variableList = variableList;
    }

    @Override
    public RVResultAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.result_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RVResultAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Variable v = variableList.get(position);
        holder.setItems(v);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return variableList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textView1;
        TextView textView2;
        TextView textView3;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.result_name_tv);
            textView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.result_value_tv);
            textView3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.result_unit_tv);
        }

        public void setItems (Variable variable) {
            textView1.setText(variable.getName());
            textView2.setText(String.format("%.3f", variable.getValue()));
            textView3.setText(variable.getUnit());
        }
    }
}
```

**`Result` class**

```
public class Result extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ArrayList<Variable> rList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String tag = intent.getExtras().getString("tag");

        if (tag.equals("serie")) {
            SerieActivity serieActivity = new SerieActivity();
            rList = serieActivity.mList;
        }

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.result_rv);
        RVResultAdapter rvResultAdapter = new RVResultAdapter(this, rList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(rvResultAdapter);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        rvResultAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

My problem is with the RecyclerView in `Result`. It shows the blue "end of content" things when I scroll up and down, so I guess the RecyclerView *is* there, but doesn't get any data. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am quite new to Android and Java programming, so I guess it must be a dumb thing that I just don't see.

Comment: Definitly to much code here! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you calling `SerieActivity` constructor in `Results` activity and execute `populateList()` inside `onCreate()`. You shouldn't create activities in this way because `onCreate()` will be never called. Instead of this you should pass data using `putExtra` and use `Parcelable` interface.

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing dude. How can you get list from a new object of `SerieActivity.class`?

> ```
>     if (tag.equals("serie")) {
>         SerieActivity serieActivity = new SerieActivity();
>         rList = serieActivity.mList;
>     }
> ```

This is totally wrong way. If you want to pass list between activities. You can use parcelable methods `putExtra` and `getExtra`.

Assuming that your List is a list of strings make data an `ArrayList<String>` and use `intent.putStringArrayListExtra("data", data)`

Here is a skeleton of the code you need:

First you need to create a Parcelable object class, see the example

```
public class Student implements Parcelable {

        int id;
        String name;

        public Student(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;

        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }


        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dest.writeInt(id);
            dest.writeString(name);
        }

        public Student(Parcel in) {
            id = in.readInt();
            name = in.readString();
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<Student> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Student>() {
            public Student createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Student(in);
            }

            public Student[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Student[size];
            }
        };
    }
```

#### And the list

```
ArrayList<Student> arraylist = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

#### Code from Calling activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("mylist", arraylist);
intent.putExtras(bundle);       
this.startActivity(intent);
```

#### Code on called activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);   

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    ArrayList<Student> arraylist = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("mylist");
}
```

Comment: You already know how to auto generate parcelable code for model class?

Comment: no, I don't, but I'll do some research on this. I'll try the plugin ASAP, looks extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

just set the recyclerview code like this first initialize adapter then set layout manager and then set to adapter to recyclerview.

recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

```
    mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(movieList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    prepareMovieData();
```